# C# iterate over a row in Excel

Tags: c#, excel

I need to iterate over a specific excel row. For now I've got a code to iterate over a column and I want it to be similar to that. It looks like this:

```
int columnLength = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
string lastCell = Regex.Replace(CONST_FIRST_CELL, @"\d+", columnLength.ToString()); //will give me the last cell in the column
var excelColumn = xlWorkSheet.Range[CONST_FIRST_CELL, lastCell ];
    if (excelColumn == null)
    {
      throw new Exception("bad col");
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < columnLength ; i++)
    {
      Excel.Range currentValue = excelColumn [i];
      ....DO SOME STUFF....
    }
```

how can I iterate over a specific row? I'm not sure how to get the last column like I got the last row cell in the above implementation since then I just had to switch a number with the length but now I somehow need to get the correct last cell of a row (which means switching the letters somehow i.e C4 to AD4) in order to get the range of first cell row and last...

The best solution I guess involves a foreach loop somehow?

Comment: please post us what library you are using to read from Excel like OpenXml / Office dll etc..

Comment: Your code is a bit confusing. You are defining variables called "column" and assigning rows values to them. Also I am not sure about the way in which you get the last cell by relying on regex. Could you please explain exactly what you want to accomplish? Just iterating through rows? Also, as suggested by saravanan, please tell the specific library you are using; I assumed that it was interop connection but perhaps is not; what would explain some of the parts I don't understand in your code.

Comment: @saravanan I'm using .NET's Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Comment: @varocarbas I've got a specific row, for example row number 5 and now I want to iterate over each cell in that row and get the content of the current cell I'm over.

Comment: Much clearer, I have written an answer including the required corrections in your loop to accomplish what you are after -> ranges (and values) for all the cells in the given row from the startCol to the maxCol columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there, your loop just needs some tuning:

```
  //Input all the Int values you want
  int targetRow = 1; 
  int startCol = 1;
  int maxCol = 10; //With this value the loop below will iterate until column 9 (inclusive)
  for (int i = startCol; i < maxCol ; i++)
  {
      Excel.Range currentRange = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[targetRow, i];
      if (currentRange.Value2 != null)
      {
          string curVal = currentRange.Value2.ToString();
      }
  }
```

IMO this is the best way to iterate through cells (by considering rows and/or columns). You can do it differently (on the lines of what you were trying): iterating within the columns of a given range (you would need to define the range as `Excel.Range` Type and then rely on the in-built property `Columns`), although I think that this can be more confusing. Example: if you have as input range C1:H5, "C:C" is the first column, "D:D" the second column, etc. With my approach, the first column will always be "A:A", the second column "B:B", etc.

Example of iterating through columns in a given range (`inputRange`):

```
foreach(Excel.Range curCol in inputRange.Columns)
{
    if (curCol.Value2 != null) 
    {
       //As far as each column only has one row, each column can be associated with a cell
        string curVal = curCol.Value2.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the difference between the Cells attribute of the work sheet and the Range attribute? And don't you need to give it a range of specific cells?

Comment: @YonatanNir I have precisely updated my answer right now with a clarification on this front: with Cells (from the sheet) you get an absolute reference for column indexing: 1 will be always associated with column A. Read my comment and let me know about your impressions.

Comment: So just let's see if I got this correctly... The way I used to iterate over columns in my code is good for when you have a specific start cell and an end cell, and your approach is better when trying to iterate over a full row/col from it's start and for as many cells you want? And the cells attribute receives because of that, not a range of a specific start and end cell but rather just a row and a column? 
Just what is "C:C"? I understand it's the column "C" but what is the other "C" stands for?

Comment: @YonatanNir I have re-updated my answer to show something on the lines of what you were trying. See, you can define a range in many ways: Range("A1") = Cells[1, 1] (and many other options). When iterating through Columns, you might prefer the second option because of being easier than dealing with letters. On top of that you have the columns/rows collections (none of them rely on letters)...

Comment: @YonatanNir the difference between what you proposed and what I proposed is not the way in which the ranges are defined/iterated (which, at the end, is basically the same) but what are the original ranges taken as reference. In your case you are taking as a reference a range defined by yourself (which, as said, does not need to start from A1); in my case, I am taking the default spreadsheet range (always starting from A1). This is the main difference between your approach and mine (or between my first code and my second code)